# Is the Bugtraker .NET tools is free tool or paid up one?

Tags: .net, bug-tracking, bugtracker.net

I want to use Bug tracker .net tool for defect tracking. But in this tool there is no report option.
Any one can please suggest me, whether the Bug Tracker .NET tool for defect tracking is free tool or we need to pay to access this tool.
Thanks in advance

Comment: From the FRONT PAGE of the website "BugTracker.NET is a free, open-source..."

Comment: I can't see how this is a question that is relevant to StackOverflow? Even if it wasn't obvious from the front page, this was something to ask the developer(s).

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean this one? http://ifdefined.com/bugtrackernet.html

> BugTracker.NET is a **free**, open-source, web-based bug tracker

Comment: Hello Greg, thanks for your suggestions, I am inviting you on the "Tester's Talk" room for chating or reviewing the queries and answers. Thank you.